# 00984. 00000 - "column not allowed here"

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to create following PL/sql but getting error

Create new anonymous PL/SQL block that:

- first, selects total number of employees, their average salary, their maximum salary and their minimum salary from the employees table into PL/SQL variables. Average salary should be rounded to a whole number
- then creates a table stats with the following columns:

  ```
  the_date   DATE,                                        
  emp_num NUMBER                              
  avg_sal   NUMBER                                    
  max_sal   NUMBER                                
  min_sal   NUMBER
  ```
- then inserts into the stats table values of today’s date, total number of employees, their average salary, their maximum salary and their minimum salary using mentioned above PL/SQL variables
- and finally prints on the screen.

my code:

```
DECLARE
 v_emp_no Number;
 v_av_sal Number;
 v_mx_sal Number;
 v_mn_sal Number;
BEGIN
 SELECT count(employee_id) as total_emp, ROUND(AVG(salary))as avg_sal, MAX(salary)as max_sal, MIN(salary)as min_sal
 INTO v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal
 FROM employees;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE stats (the_date DATE, emp_num NUMBER, avg_sal NUMBER, max_sal NUMBER, min_sal NUMBER)';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO stats values (sysdate, v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal)';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE stats';
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Today our company has '||v_emp_no||' emplyees');
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The average salary in the company is '||v_av_sal);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The maximum salary in the company is '||v_mx_sal);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The minimum salary in the company is '||v_mn_sal);
END;
/
```

but getting following error

```
Error report -
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at line 11
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Why PL/SQL when the same could be done in plain SQL.

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO stats values (sysdate, v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal)';
```

The variable names are not referencing your variables, but are treated as column names.

You need to use bind variables for this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO stats values (sysdate, :1, :2, :3, :4)'
  USING v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal;
```

Answer (score 0):

> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO stats values (sysdate, v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal)';

This is wrong. Because, `v_emp_no, v_av_sal, v_mx_sal, v_mn_sal` are **variables** and not **values**. You need to treat them as variables.

**EDIT**

You should not (ab)use dynamic SQL for such trivial tasks.

Step back and think, Isn't it supposed to be done in plain **SQL** rather than **PL/SQL**? That whole anonymous block is nothing but three SQL statements -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE stats
  2    (
  3      the_date DATE,
  4      emp_num  NUMBER,
  5      avg_sal  NUMBER,
  6      max_sal  NUMBER,
  7      min_sal  NUMBER
  8    );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO stats
  2  SELECT sysdate,
  3    COUNT(empno)    AS total_emp,
  4    ROUND(AVG(sal)) AS avg_sal,
  5    MAX(sal)        AS max_sal,
  6    MIN(sal)        AS min_sal
  7  FROM emp;

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM stats;

THE_DATE     EMP_NUM    AVG_SAL    MAX_SAL    MIN_SAL
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
30-JAN-15         14       2073       5000        800

SQL>
SQL> DROP TABLE stats PURGE;

Table dropped.
```

Comment: Bind variables rather than concatenation, surely?

Comment: Yes, good point. I would rather not use PL/SQL and do it in plain SQL. Edited my answer.

Comment: I assume it's an exercise; otherwise why bother with the table anyway, why not just use the plain `select` on its own? Either way creating and dropping the table seems... excessive.

Comment: Well, agreed. However, table like stats are not always supposed to be just a select. In the world of analytics, for creating BI dashboards, a table like stats makes sense.

Comment: Sure, but not creating it and dropping it immediately. Who knows what is in the OP's mind though *8-)